# Copying a new string in MIPS

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, stack, mips

So this program takes a string of a "dirty" formula "12.0 + (34 - 45) *A67/z89
and prints the "clean" formula "120+(34-45)*67/89
The cleanFormula method only takes digits 0-9, arithmetic operators + - * /, and parentheses as valid characters. The rest get iterated over.

The problem I'm having with this program is: My Iteration loop works correctly, my copy copies all the characters to my stack, and my cleaning loop iterates over invalid chars, stores all valid characters in $t2, and jumps to printFormula for valid characters that are not digits.

BUT printFormula is not printing my modified string. Rather, it's printing the original string. Can anyone help me with this? I feel like it's a matter of putting values on a stack for printFormula at this point since printFormula has the instruction sw $a0, 8($sp)

# Combines test12 and test13.

```
# From test12:
# Changes $s register usage in main to make sure cleanFormula is not relying
# on getting values from main by way of the $s registers..

# From test13:
# printFormula appends " -- from printFormula" to each line. This is to
# confirm that printFormula is being called.

.data


mainFormulas:
         .word    mainFormula2
         .word    mainFormula1
         .word    mainFormula3
         .word    mainFormula4

mainNumFormulas:
         .word    4

mainFormula1:
         .asciiz   "1742163829863897628673002651087650871620387650876540817263087612035897601287650128973501982650986508716408172658765987506501297568751078965"
mainFormula2:
         .asciiz   "((((((slkdj*+-+++------))))))((((****///soifh//***lskdhgoiuy****---+++))))"
mainFormula3:
         .asciiz   "1"
mainFormula4:
         .asciiz   "a"

mainNewline:
        .asciiz "\n"

.data
mainOrigStr:
         .asciiz "In main, original formula: "

.text
main:
         # Function prologue -- even main has one
         addiu $sp, $sp, -24      # allocate stack space -- default of 24 here
         sw    $fp, 0($sp)        # save frame pointer of caller
         sw    $ra, 4($sp)        # save return address
         addiu $fp, $sp, 20       # setup frame pointer of main

         # for ( i = 0; i < mainNumFormulas; i++ )
         #    print the original string
         #    cleanFormula
         #    print the original string

         addi  $s5, $zero, 0      # $s5 = i = 0
         la    $t0, mainNumFormulas
         lw    $s6, 0($t0)        # $s6 = number of strings
         la    $s7, mainFormulas  # $s7 = addr mainFormulas[0]
mainLoopBegin:
         slt   $t0, $s5, $s6      # $t0 = i < mainNumFormulas
         beq   $t0, $zero, mainLoopEnd

         lw    $s1, 0($s7)        # $s1 = addr of start of current string

         # print the original formula

         la    $a0, mainOrigStr
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         addi  $a0, $s1, 0
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         la    $a0, mainNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         addi  $a0, $s1, 0        # $a0 = addr of string start

         jal   cleanFormula

         # print the original formula

         la    $a0, mainOrigStr
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         lw    $a0, 0($s7)        # $a0 = addr of start of current string
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         la    $a0, mainNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall
         syscall                  # print blank line

         addi  $s5, $s5, 1        # i++
         addi  $s7, $s7, 4        # $s7 = addr of next string
         j     mainLoopBegin

mainLoopEnd:

mainDone:
         # Epilogue for main -- restore stack & frame pointers and return
         lw    $ra, 4($sp)        # get return address from stack
         lw    $fp, 0($sp)        # restore frame pointer of caller
         addiu $sp, $sp, 24       # restore stack pointer of caller
         jr    $ra                # return to caller


printFormula:

.data
printFormulaNewline:
         .asciiz " -- from printFormula\n"
.text
 # Function prologue
         addiu $sp, $sp, -24      # allocate stack space -- default of 24 here
         sw    $fp,  0($sp)       # save frame pointer of caller
         sw    $ra,  4($sp)       # save return address
         sw    $a0,  8($sp)       # save $a0 = addr of first char to print
         sw    $a1, 12($sp)       # save $a1 = how many chars to print
         addiu $fp, $sp, 20       # setup frame pointer of printFormula

         # for (i = $a0; i < $a0 + $a1; i++)
         #    print byte

         addi  $t0, $a0, 0        # i = $t0 = start of characters to print
         add   $t1, $a0, $a1      # $t1 = addr of last character to print

printFormulaLoopBegin:
         slt   $t2, $t0, $t1      # $t2 = i < $a0 + $a1
         beq   $t2, $zero, printFormulaLoopEnd

         # print the character
         lb    $a0, 0($t0)
         addi  $v0, $zero, 11
         syscall

         addi  $t0, $t0, 1        # i++
         j     printFormulaLoopBegin

printFormulaLoopEnd:
         la    $a0, printFormulaNewline
         addi  $v0, $zero, 4
         syscall

         # Epilogue for printFormula -- restore stack & frame pointers & return
         lw    $a1, 12($sp)       # restore $a1
         lw    $a0,  8($sp)       # restore $a0
         lw    $ra,  4($sp)       # get return address from stack
         lw    $fp,  0($sp)       # restore frame pointer of caller
         addiu $sp, $sp, 24       # restore stack pointer of caller
         jr    $ra                # return to caller

         #Your code goes below this line

#cleanFormula
#Takes a string formula and "cleans" it
#To do this: the formula is copied into a new string
#New string only copies digits 0 - 9, parentheses, and
#mathematic operators + - * /
#cleanFormula calls printFormula to print the "clean" formula

cleanFormula:
# Prologue: set up stack and frame pointers for printFormula
         addiu   $sp, $sp, -24    # allocate stack space -- default of 24
         sw      $fp, 0($sp)      # save frame pointer of caller
         sw      $ra, 4($sp)      # save return address
         addi    $fp, $sp, 20     # setup frame pointer for cleanFormula

        # We need to make additional space to hold each character of the the
        # string. To do this, we iterate through the string to get the
        # string length then we add this to our stack
        # We do this in loopStringIterationBegin
        # $a0 is the address of the string
        # initialize $t1 to count = 0

        addi    $t1, $zero, 0   # $t1 = count = 0

cleanFormulaLoopStringIterationBegin:

        # Base case
        lb      $t0, 0($a0)     # $t0 = address of string
        beq     $t0, $zero, cleanFormulaLoopStringIterationEnd

        # while ( char !=  null)
        #count++
        #  Where string is null, count = length
        # add 1 to $a0 to continue iterating over string

        addi    $t1, $t1, 1     # $t1 = count++
        addi    $a0, $a0, 1     # $a0++
        j       cleanFormulaLoopStringIterationBegin

cleanFormulaLoopStringIterationEnd:
        # $t1 is the length of our string
        # Allocate our stack space by 1 byte per character
        # in order to fit our string on the stack

        # In order to keep the stack word aligned, we have to
        # add some number to $t1 to make it divisible by 4
        # To do this: divide $t1 by 4 and subtract
        # the value of the HI register (remainder) by 4
        # our value 4 - HI is the necessary amount of bytes
        # to add to keep our stack aligned
        # However HI itself can not be used with arithmetic
        # instruction, so we move the value of HI to another 
        # register for operating

        addi    $t0, $zero, 4   # $t0 = 4 for our division
        div     $t1, $t0        # $t1/$t0 LO is quotient HI is remainder
        mfhi    $t2             # Moves mfhi to $t2 for our loop
        sub     $t2, $t0, $t2   # $t2 = 4 - HI
        add     $t3, $t1, $t2   # $t3 = $t1 + $t2

        # $t1 now has all bytes to reference each char in the 
        # string and additional bytes to keep the stack
        # aligned

        # allocate our new stack space 
        subu    $sp, $sp, $t3   # $sp = -24 - (string.length() + 4 - HI)

        # cleanFormulaCopyLoopBegin
        # Copy the characters of the string onto our stack
        # while ( char != null )
        #       character[i] onto stack
        #       i++
        # put a null  character at the end

        addi    $t2, $sp, 0     # $t2 references original sp
        sub     $a0, $a0, $t1   # restores $a0

cleanFormulaCopyLoopBegin:
         lb      $t0, 0($a0)      # $t0 = address of string
         beq     $t0, $zero, cleanFormulaCopyLoopEnd

         sb      $t0, 0($t2)      # $t2 = string[i]
         addi    $t2, $t2, 1      # $t2++
         addi    $a0, $a0, 1      # $a0++
         j       cleanFormulaCopyLoopBegin

cleanFormulaCopyLoopEnd:
        #put a null character at the end for our cleaning loop next
        sb      $zero, 0($t2)

        #set $a0 to the address of our stack

        # cleanFormulaCleanLoopBegin
        # Iterate the string by interating
        # the characters copied to the stack
        # Then comparing characters for valid characters
        # 0 - 9, parentheses, or opetarors * / - +
        # only copy valid characters, otherwise skip
        # To do this: compare ascii values
        # Ascii equivalences: 0 - 9 (48-57), ( ) (40, 41),
        #                     * (42), + (43), - (45), / (47)

        # $a1 will be the length of the string
        # Initialize $a1 at 0
        addi    $a0, $sp,   0   # $a0 = address of $sp
        addi    $a1, $zero, 0   # $a1 = 0
        addi    $t2, $sp,   0   # reset $t2 to start of stack

cleanFormulaCleanLoopBegin:
        # for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
        #       if validCharacter
        #               newString +=  thatCharacter

        #Base Case
        lb      $t0, 0($t2)     # get character
        beq     $t0, $zero, cleanFormulaCleanLoopEnd
        # When $t0 == nul character on the end of our string

        # Compare character
        # Our range of valid ascii  characters is 40 - 57 excluding
        # 44 and  46. We need 2 slti and 4 branch conditions to
        # reflect this

        slti    $t4, $t0, 58    # $t4 = char <= largest ascii digit
        beq     $t4, $zero, cleanFormulaCleanLoopIncrement

        # This says if !$t0 < 58) -> $t0 >= 58 ->  $t0 > 57
        # our highest valid ascii char (9)  then skip the character

        slti    $t4, $t0 40     #$t4 = $t0 < smallest ascii digit
        bne     $t4, $zero, cleanFormulaCleanLoopIncrement

        # This says if $t0 < 40, our lowest valid ascii char ('(')
        # then skip the character
        # 44 and 46 are also invalid ascii characters for our clean formula

        addi    $t4, $zero, 44  #$t4 = 44     
        beq     $t0, $t4, cleanFormulaCleanLoopIncrement

        addi    $t4, $zero, 46  #$t4 = 46
        beq     $t0, $t4, cleanFormulaCleanLoopIncrement

        # Only valid ascii characters are left now
        # Concatenate to a new string
        # increment $a1 to number of characters to print
        # Save $a1 before increment for reference 

        addi    $a2, $a1, 0
        addi    $a1, $a1, 1     # $a1++ 
        sb      $t0, 0($t2)     # stores character in $t2

        # printFormula is called each time an arithmetic operator
        # or parenthesis is found, so we separate digits from these
        # chars. Digits will jump to increment while these other
        # or parenthesis is found, so we separate digits from these
        # chars. Digits will jump to increment while these other
        # chars will call printFormula

        # Compare valid characters for digits (ascii 48-57)
        # We already know the min value of a character here is 57 (9)
        # and the range of digits is 48-57,
        # so if char >= 48, it is a digit

        slti    $t4, $t0, 48    #$t4 = $t0 < smallest digit (0)
        beq     $t4, $zero, cleanFormulaCleanLoopIncrement
        # If !($t0 < 48) -> $t0 >= 48 and $t0 is a digit

        # Now we only have (, ), *, +, -, / possible characters
        # jal to printFormula for the above characters
        # No further comparisons are necessary

        jal     printFormula
        # restore $t2 after jump
        # $t2 is stack pointer + $a2
        # ($a1 before increment)

        add    $t2, $sp, $a2

cleanFormulaCleanLoopIncrement:
        # increment $t1 to next member of stack
        addi    $t2, $t2, 1     # $t2++
        j       cleanFormulaCleanLoopBegin

cleanFormulaCleanLoopEnd:
        # Concatenated and printed new string formula
        # Calls printFormula one last time
        jal     printFormula

cleanFormulaDone:
        # Epilogue for cleanFormula: restore stack & frame pointers and return
        # Remove the extra bytes used by the string
        add   $sp, $sp, $t3      # Removes all extra bytes used by string

        # Now, clean up the rest of the stack
        lw      $ra, 4($sp)      # get return address from stack
        lw      $fp, 0($sp)      # restore frame pointer for caller
        addiu   $sp, $sp, 24     # restore stack pointer for caller
        jr      $ra              # return to caller
```

Comment: I just looked briefly at the code, but it seems to me like you're using the same register (`$t2`) as both the source and destination address in you clean-loop. Well, what happens when you decide to skip a character and just increment `$t2`? (hint: remember that you've not only incremented the source address, but also the destination address).

Comment: Well when I just increment $t2 it reads the next character, which it does properly. And I'm pretty sure it's storing properly too, since I had a print call to see what chars printed before the jal command and I had my cleaned formula string right, so I really don't know what the issue is.

Comment: I think you missed my point. The issue is what happens to the characters you skip over when you're doing in-place modification of a string with a single pointer for source and destination. Try it out on a piece of paper with a short string that contains at least one invalid character.

Comment: Being honest, my brain is just fried. I've been working on this for a few days now, and I've tried quite a bit of trial and error.
$a0 should pass the address of the first character and
$a1 should pass the number of characters to print. As far as I can tell, I can print my string, I tried setting sb to $a0 and I started printing sections of the string and then printing non-print characters. I'm completely stumped, hence why I'm posting on Stack Overflow

Comment: Changing the register destination only changes it to not invalid characters, but it's replacing them with the next valid character in line instead

Comment: So my $t2 register is being set improperly for some cases. What offset would I give it to store it on my stack so I can retrieve the value after jumping back from printFormula? That might fix everything.